# MAMP PRO can't be used by non-admin users

Tags: mac, privileges, mamp

I have MAMP PRO set for a Mac's admin user. But other users want to use it too. How can it be done? When a normal user try to open MAMP PRO, it shows a message saying that it needs administrator privileges.